# Should anyone hire a slow worker?

Tags: work-time

I have a mild form of cerebral palsy and this makes me worry that should I ever get a job. I found during my university studies that I am about 40 % slower student than average friend. Still, I managed to get better than average grades when I made my exams after I learned things on my own schedule.

Will any company hire a people who can do things well if he or she will be given enough time, or should I start a single man company?

Comment: Can you get things done in a reasonable time span and at the required quality? Because, that's really all companies really care about. You don't have to be the absolute best (let alone the fastest) in order to get a job.

Comment: It depends. Often I could do it but sometimes I feel that I need a Benjamin Gruenbaumbit more guidance than others. I tried once to work in a company I felt that I had not enough time to learn the softwares company used and I misunderstood what the customer wants, so that went guite badly. But I tried one project on my own and I was able to ask the customer the details of what she wants and she was happy to my work.

Comment: @CP-dude seconding what Benjamin said, employers will often be happier with a *more reliable* employee, even if they're slower. So if you can prove that you can deliver consistent, quality results in the desired time frame, how fast you work beyond that is irrelevant.

Comment: "Do you want it done fast, or do you want it done right?"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The classic disability management idea is that if the person with the disability can be reasonably accommodated, they have every right to be.  Where the problem is knowledge absorption, rather than physical access or mobility, the challenge would boil down to the idea that as long as you can produce the desired quality with the desired schedule, there's no reason NOT to hire you or retain you once you are hired.

That definition of "reasonable accommodation" means that it has be reasonable to both parties.  Businesses need a certain level of quality in any product or service they provide, or they will loose business from unhappy customers.  And they need to be able to provide that product or service within a certain time frame, in order to capture a certain market position (being first to market is always a big deal).  So they company can't reasonably change these criteria for success.

However, they CAN reasonably provide you with:

- as many (reasonably priced) tools as you may be able to make use of for learning the job.
- the flexibility for you to study extra hard - in fact, most knowledge work jobs figure that you will take whatever time you need to learn whatever you need to learn
- some flexibility in getting verification of the quality of your output in timely manner - for example, they could reasonably spare someone to peer review your work more often while you are coming up to speed, so you get more feedback than another would.  Particularly since you won't need it ALWAYS, only while you are learning.

It sounds like if you've been a good student, this would be sufficient?  You've already had to learn hard stuff, and demonstrate your knowledge within a specific time frame... so if you are pulling off good grades, you are essentially demonstrating the willingness to work hard for what you want.

What I find is that people who don't fit the norm in any industry, particularly those with a justifiable disability, don't always get the best help or advocacy, so they end up having to learn to advocate for themselves.  In the end, whether you are a one man shop, or an employee, you'll end up needing to learn how to best frame yourself and your learning needs in a way that works for both you and the company.

As a boss, what this works out to is that my employees and I do best when they are able to be as clear as possible in telling me what they need from me, and what I can do to help them.  That's even more true when there's a challenge that I understand very little about (I don't have cerebral palsy, although I had a college classmate who did) - helping me help you means you get more useful help.

In practice, I've worked with several people with learning disabilities and sometimes I didn't even know it... sometimes I did, and was able to help with getting them what they needed to create great work.

Comment: "_...or they will loose business from unhappy customers..._" - If my boot is loose I might lose it. (I'd have fixed this for you but think it is too minor in order to do so.)

Answer (score 4):

> Should anyone hire a slow worker?

Yes. Sometimes a slow worker is better than a fast one. It is sometimes more important to get something done right, than having it done fast.

For any project or task there are usually multiple competing objectives, some examples could be:

- Get it done within a specific time frame
- Ensure quality of deliverable to be at least of a certain grade
- Ensure interests of all stakeholders are well represented
- Ensure continuity in terms of documentation and process workflows
- Plan for contingencies

While it sounds like you are disadvantaged in terms of delivering things faster, perhaps you are better at the other points? I suggest you evaluate your strengths and seek out roles and companies where they would be more valuable.